# Uninstalled Python3.x, Reinstalled and now won't run files

Tags: python-3.x, directory, uninstallation, reinstall

I had Python3.5.1. I accidentally downloaded it in like 3 spots a while back, and had some issues with Pip install, so i figured I`d uninstall them all then download it again. So, since there was only 1 Launcher and 1 Python3.x in programs + files, I had to manually delete the files of the other two. (Oops?) Now that Python3.x has been reinstalled, none of my old .py files work. They give me errors, or don't open. Also, I have to manually choose the way to open (not just double click runs it), and all platforms just run it in a py.exe, so i can't see errors. I think this image has something to do with it: [When I double click the .py to run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY82p.png)

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Try running python from cmd and paste the output...

Comment: File search > cmd, i type in python, and it opens like normal as a cmd shell

Comment: OK, try right clicking a python file and setting the 'Open With' program to 'Python'. (I can't help you perfectly here, because I run Xubuntu, not MS-Windows)

Comment: Opens window then closes. I can't open any .py file without it closing, and I can't see any error message because it closes too fast. If I try to open it in cmd, it opens a seperate .py window that closes fast

Comment: Try putting `print("Testing...");sleep(5);` in a python file, and run it and tell me the output.

Comment: I think issue is this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YY82p.png, because that dir doesnt exist.

Comment: I ran 'import time
from time import sleep
for x in range(0,4):
     print('Testing'+'.'*x) ; sleep(1)' and got the expected result.